# Views page and AJAX

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I created a page view where it lists all nodes grouped by content types. My problem is how to create a page which will only output the view, I mean without the headers, sidebars etc.. just the view content? My reason for doing this is I would later call the view / view page in an AJAX request and display to the user.

My view name is 'node_list', and I used the files views-view-list--node-list.tpl.php and views-view-fields--node-list--page.tpl.php to theme the output. But I have no idea how to create a page with only the view visible..

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing, is to create the call back for the ajax function and just return the view you want to insert using [`views_embed_view`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_embed_view)

Comment: I was also thinking of creating a page.tpl.php for the view named 'node_list' but then i couldnt get the fields theming to work.

By the way , I enabled the pager and set it to ajax. In Firebug I can see the request , the parameters and the response. Maybe i just need to mimic that behavior in my JS file.. 

Thanks for your reply Sir!